# Laravel controller store data received in camel case format

Tags: php, laravel, database, api

I'm working with multiple controllers where I receive inputs in camel case format and I need to assign these properties to a model:

```
$scopeCommercial = new ScopeCommercial();
$scopeCommercial->lifetime_sales = $request->lifetimeSales;
$scopeCommercial->lifetime_volumes = $request->lifetimeVolumes;
```

The problem is that my model has around 30 properties and I don't want to write them one by one.
I know that I can use the [request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-all-input-data) to get all the properties:

```
$input = $request->all();
```

Is there a way to convert match the properties in camel case format with the database standard equivalent? Something like the inverse of [camel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-camel-case) method:

```
$converted = Str::camel('foo_bar');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$converted = Str::snake('fooBar', '_');
```

more https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-snake-case